# #include excel error in C++ with Visual Studio 2015, Community edition

Tags: c++, excel

I am trying to visualize my experimental data in excel. The following import statement give me errors:

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\MSO.DLL" rename("DocumentProperties", "DocumentPropertiesXL") rename("RGB", "RGBXL")
#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"
#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE" rename("DialogBox", "DialogBoxXL") rename("RGB", "RGBXL") rename("DocumentProperties", "DocumentPropertiesXL") rename("ReplaceText", "ReplaceTextXL") rename("CopyFile", "CopyFileXL") no_dual_interfaces
```

The location is correct because I literally copy and paste the location.

However I get the error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C1083   Cannot open type library file: 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office12\mso.dll': No such file or directory

But this file or directory definitely exists. My professor said that I need administrative access, but I don't know what that means and how to change this. 
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Not sure if matters in MS world, but if I was in your shoes I'd try escaping all the backslashes (add an extra backslash [each \ becomes \\ ] )  just to see if it makes a difference. If it doesn't, change them back ;-)

Comment: @John3136 That has no effect for me

Answer (score -1):

You did not run it as an administrator, so you cannot access folders requiring administrator access. You need to run it as admin. Read more [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html).

Comment: How do I do this for .sln files? The "Run as adminstrator" does now show up when I right click.

Comment: @Ryan, read this article: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/04/open-your-solution-files-as-admin.html

Comment: I got it running as admisistrator, but same error persists:(

Comment: Then you should tell your professor that despite the fact that you have followed the instructions, the problem persists.